# Asp.Net Active Directory Login does not work when domain provided in Chrome and IE

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, windows-authentication

This is one weird issue.

*Some* users in our AD cannot access out intranet website when they are using IE/Chrome and specifythe domain in their username.  Strangely enough, if they try to login with the domain in firefox, the login works fine.  In chrome and IE, if they don't specify domain, login also works.

I've developed my app using Asp.Net MVC 5.1.

Is there anything that can be causing this behavior?

**Update**: This issue started happening after one of the devs attempted to update the timeout on the application pool. We've reverted the change but still have the same issue. **Other webapps on the same server do not have this issue.**  yes, I've double checked with the dev, and that was the only change he made.

Comment: I think this is more of a question specific to IE than ASP.NET MVC. Chrome uses IE's Windows Authentication and proxy settings so it makes sense that they both exhibit the same behaviour. Try playing with the `Local intranet` settings under the security tab in Internet Options.

Comment: @RowanFreeman Unfortunately, this started happening after the dev made a change to IIS, which he has already reverted.  I've added more details in the question.  Which is why I'm most certain that it's got something to do with IIS.

Answer (score 0):

I have not been able to identify what the issue is.  My primary fix is this:

1. Go to IIS and click on your web app
2. Click on Authentication
3. Click on Windows Authentication and then click on Providers on the right
4. Remove Negotiate.

What we're doing here is always enforcing NTLM login method.  What negotiate does is choose between NTLM and Kerbos to do the login.  Kerbos essentially has implementation of SPN allowing auto login.  Whereas, NTLM does not do auto login.  For instance, client applications like Mozilla or your own desktop application may not have integrated with SPN by default, so Negotiate will choose NTML for authentication.  IE and Chrome on the other hand by default have this, so  Negotiate chooses kerbos.

I'm still interested in understanding why I'm having this issue, but for now, this is a workaround.